# QGIS Export Webmap with QGIS2Web only using Python Console?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, qgis2web

I want to automatically export my QGIS map to Webmap using only pyQGIS commands. By now I just know how to run the plugin with commands on python console:

```
import qgis.utils
qgis2web = qgis.utils.plugins["qgis2web"] 
qgis2web.run()
```

but I dont know how to export the Webmap.

Comment: You can call the qgis2web processing algorithms. However, they are currently broken in QGIS3.

Comment: Did you by any chance find a way to do this?